# PHP & HTML help for editing password because it is in MD5

Tags: php, html, textfield, edit

I have build one edit form in HTML. I am accessing that value in PHP. There is one field **PASSWORD**. In which I have displayed password for edit which is in MD5 format and stored in **mysql** database. But when I am not changing it, it should be unchanged and should not be converted. Is there anyone who can help me ?

Comment: you might need to provide some of your code

Answer (score 1):

Rather than let the user edit their password, you should let them reset their password.

Answer (score 1):

You should not display the password on the form anyway! You should just display a blank empty box. When the you post the form back on the server you should check if the $_POST['password']==null and NOT proceed with changing the password. If the user enters a password the you should md5 the value and store it. What i usually do is first send the user an email with a random password and ask him to change it the first time he enters it!

CHeers.

Comment: thanx a lot i will try based on your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Standard convention would be to leave the password field blank, with a message that says something like "Enter and confirm password to change it." Then on your form handler, if password is blank, don't update it in the database.

You should never display the MD5 encrypted password to the user.

Answer (score 0):

MD5 is one way encryption, so you will have to ask the security question, if it is correct then ask him to provide a new password which you should encrypt using md5 and store in database.